# Store ints into array from a file and find primes JAVA

Tags: java, arrays, java.util.scanner, primes

In this interactive program, you will find a menu with options to perform different functions on an array. This array is taken from a file called "data.txt". The file contains integers, one per line. Obviously, I have not included the entire code (it was too long). However, I was hoping that someone could help me with the problem of finding the prime numbers in the array Right now, the console prints the address of the array for the primes ([I@4a13ccea). Any suggestions are welcome. Part of my program is below. Thanks.

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws FileNotFoundException {
    Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
    System.out.println("Welcome to Calculation Program!\n");
    startMenus(sc);

}

private static void startMenus(Scanner sc) throws FileNotFoundException {
    while (true) {
        System.out.println("(Enter option # and press ENTER)\n");

        System.out.println("1. Display the average of the list");
        System.out.println("2. Display the number of occurences of a given element in the list");
        System.out.println("3. Display the prime numbers in a list");
        System.out.println("4. Display the information above in table form");
        System.out.println("5. Save the information onto a file in table form");
        System.out.println("6. Exit");

        int option = sc.nextInt();

        sc.nextLine();

        switch (option) {
            case 1:
                System.out.println("You've chosen to compute the average.");
                infoMenu1(sc);
                break;
            case 2:
                infoMenu2(sc, sc);
                break;
            case 3:
                infoMenu3(sc);
                break;
            case 4:
                infoMenu4(sc);
                break;
            case 5:
                infoMenu5(sc);
                break;
            case 6:
                System.exit(0);
            default:

                System.out.println("Unrecognized Option!\n");
        }

    }
}
private static void infoMenu3(Scanner sc) throws FileNotFoundException {
    File file = new File("data.txt");
    sc = new Scanner(file);

    int[] numbers = new int[100];

    int i = 0;

    while (sc.hasNextInt()) {
        numbers[i] = sc.nextInt();
        ++i;
    }

    for (int j = 0; j < i; ++j) {
        System.out.print("The numbers in the file are: " + numbers[j] + " ");
    }
}
public static boolean prime(int x) {
    boolean answer = true;

    for (int i = 2; i <= x / 2; i = i + 1) {
        if (i != x) {
            if (i % x == 0) {
                answer = false;
            }
        }
    }

    return answer;
}

public static int[] primes(int[] numbers) {
    int primesCount = 0;

    for (int i : numbers) {
        if (prime(i)) {
            primesCount = (primesCount + 1);
        }
    }

    if (primesCount == 0) {
        return null;
    }

    int[] result = new int[primesCount];
    int index = 0;

    for (int i : numbers) {
        if (prime(i)) {
            result[index] = i;
            index = index + 1;
        }
    }

    return result;
}
}
```

Comment: Maybe you want to return `result[index]` instead of `result`.

Comment: Returning 'result[index]' changes my method return type to 'int'. I would like it to return 'int[]'.

Comment: You should loop on `numbers` and print for each iteration `primes(numbers)` but you should return `result[index]` instead.. (If I'm not misunderstanding you)

Answer (score 1):

Loop through your array and print every element, or use the `java.util.Arrays.toString(int[])` method if its format suits your needs.

Comment: I can print every element or convert the array into a string, but that will print every integer including the non-prime numbers. And my primes method cannot find prime numbers from a string...

Comment: Call this method on the array of prime numbers. i.e. replace `System.out.println("The primes in the file are: " + primes(numbers));` by `System.out.println("The primes in the file are: " + Arrays.toString(primes(numbers)));`

Comment: I changed the code so it would print every element, but I'm not sure how I would evaluate each element individually to test for prime

Comment: Don't you have that logic already? Doesn't the primes() method return the array of prime numbers? If so, print this array using `Arrays.toString()`.

Answer (score 0):

Two marks

If you print an array like this, you will get the address of the array, not the inside.

```
System.out.println("The primes in the file are: " + primes(numbers));
```

Replace this line with a loop that iterates over `primes(numbers)`

The second is, in your `public static boolean prime(int x)` function you have this line

```
for (int i = 2; i <= x / 2; i = i + 1)
```

Although this works, to find a prime yo do not need to iterate until **x / 2** . For performance benefits **Square root of x** would suit better.

Comment: I changed the code so it would print every element, but I'm not sure how I would evaluate each element individually to test for prime

Comment: Since this seems like an assignment I do not want to give a complete code. 1-) Read integer to your array (done) 2-) int[] myPrimes = primes(numbers) 3-) Iterate over myPrimes and output the result